# Como trabalhar com segurança em uma API + Android?

Tags: php, android, json, api

Estou precisando desenvolver uma API que receberá os dados de um usuário em json via $_GET com PHP, que irá fazer a verificação dos dados e retornar um valor verdadeiro ou falso para a aplicação Android.

Atualmente estou utilizando criptografia AES para enviar o json via $_GET, onde a API irá utilizar a chave para descriptgrafar e retornar os dados necessários, porém acredito que não seja um sistema muito seguro, pois qualquer usuário poderia acessar a URL da API diretamente pelo browser (Apesar de não poder utiliza-la por não possuir a Chave).

Gostaria de saber como posso melhorar esse sistema em termos de segurança.

/* Obs */

Atualmente como a minha aplicação precisa criptografar os dados e enviar para a API, para que depois ocorra o inverso, eu guardo uma Chave de criptografia em uma variável dentro do APK, o que não é algo realmente seguro pois a aplicação pode ser quebrada, e com o código fonte disponível qualquer um terá acesso a chave da API.

Comment: Implementaçao de um sistema de segurance depende muito do problema e do "medo" que vc tem. Qual e o perigo exatamente? O que vc precisa evitar? A interceptação. dos dados enviadas? A interceptação. da reposta? Modificação da resposta? Dos dados?

Comment: Um dethale: com um feramenta tipo xdaAutoTool, precisa de 2 minutos para quebrar um APK e com JDecomp precisa de 2 outros minutos para quebrar o JAR e ter o codigo fonte... Isso significa que, se vc tem a "chave" dentro do seu codigo, o nivel de seguranca e mas o menos de 0.

Comment: Isso mesmo, Peter.

Atualmente o meu problema é que a API é completamente acessível através da URL pelo Browser, como por exemplo: http://host/APIServer/server.php?query=DADOS_CRIPTOGRAFADOS

E como a API recebe os dados criptografados para descriptografar com AES, efetuar a requisição (Login de usuário por exemplo) e depois retornar os valores criptografados, qualquer coisa que seja adicionada ao parâmetro query da URL irá retornar algum valor qualquer que não significará nada se a chave não combinar, mas se o usuário tiver essa chave poderá resgatar qualquer dado do usuário.

Comment: Ponto 1, precisa enviar usando POST. Outro ponto, se eu entende bem, o que vc quer fazer e a identificaçao sobre o PHP? Eu tenho o aplicativo, vou me conectar no PHP e o PHP vai saber que sou eu. isso? A pergunta principal e saber se vc quer identificar o usuario (entao uma pessoa que pode digitar a senha) o se vc quer identificar o applicativo Android (entao, sem cuidar de quem usa).

Comment: No caso, eu quero identificar o usuário que está acessando e fez o login no formulário, este formulário irá fazer a validação através da API.

Comment: A chave poderia vir junto no GET/resposta do POST, assim não seria necessário guarda-la no app, se ela vem encriptada ou não, é outra historia. Não da pra garantir 100%  como já foi dito em outras perguntas, mas da pra fazer de uma forma que leve mais tempo que o "cracker" quer gastar nas suas tentativas, vale usar tudo o que estiver ao seu alcance para dificultar isso. Você poderia até fragmentar a chave de descriptografia, para confundir mais. Use SSL sempre que puder, em todas as transações.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma das implementações adicionais que você pode utilizar é a autenticação *HTTP*, assim será solicitado o utilizador entrar com um nome de usuário e senha, seja por onde for que ele acesse sua *API*.

Costumo fazer isso utilizando os arquivos `.htaccess` e `.htpasswd`.

No `.htaccess`, que fica na raiz da sua *API*, tem algo assim:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Minha API"
AuthUserFile /path/api/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

E no arquivo `.htpasswd` você possui os usuários com permissão de acesso. Este arquivo você pode deixar ele fora do diretório da sua *API*, naturalmente onde o acesso não é público. **[Aqui](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/)** tem uma ferramenta que você pode gerar esta linha para o arquivo, mas um exemplo seria assim:

```
paulo:$apr1$BrHTIveu$TfxuDimtsqm/LX6w9GL1f1
```

Ou seja, somente o usuário *paulo* tem permissão para autenticar com a senha "senha" pelo exemplo acima.

Feito isso, no lado do **Android**, você precisa acrescentar ao cabeçalho de sua requisição estas informações. Nossa forma de autenticação é a **BA** (*[HTTP Basic Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)*), portanto neste ponto temos:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authBase64);
```

Sendo que `connection` tomei como exemplo uma implementação com a classe [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) e `authBase64` é o nome de usuário e senha em **Base 64** assim: `usuario:senha`. Exemplo:

```
String authBase64 = Base64.encodeToString("paulo:senha".getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

É basicamente isso, uma das formas que você teria de acrescentar mais um passo da segurança de acesso à sua *API*.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Sim, um bom passo extra, além desse também pode deixar de utilizar GET e utilizar POST com mais criptografia e utilizar SSL.

Comment: Se a chave a "dentro" do codigo do APP Android, criptographia o HTTP vão mudar nada. Precisa de 10 minutos pra quebrar o codigo de um APP Android, achar a chave e usar.

Comment: Outro ponto importante é utilizar algo como MCrypt para encriptar os dados enviados e recebidos, assim nenhum sniffer cheira dados de sua API.

Comment: @Peter Sendo assim, nada que for feito é 100%. Como eu disse, é uma das implementações para ir diminuindo as chances. Acessando o endereço direto tem muito mais possibilidades do que alguém quebrar um código de APP (e souber fazer isso).

Comment: Qual seria então a melhor forma de guardar essa Chave de criptografia? já que não posso deixar dentro do APK.

Comment: @Paulo para quebrar um codigo Android, Google e o seu amigo. Tem doc e tem video mostrando como fazer. Sobre o comentario de Raphael, a pergunta da a resposta. Raphael pergunta "melhor forma de guardar essa chave". A boa pergunta é "porque GUARDAR a chave?" ;)

Comment: Se alguém pode acessar o código do aplicativo e encontrar a senha e o método de conexão com a API não existe motivos de utilizar criptografia mesmo, então como assegurar que APENAS o aplicativo tenha acesso as informações da API?